# Why wont my scaling matrix work?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

I am making a 2d tower defense. I am trying to get all of my images to scale to the screen size but it won't work. Using this code the result is that my background doesn't scale to the screen, my towers don't scale, and I assume my enemies spawn off the screen (and don't scale).

Initialization of  matrix:

```
       protected override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
            screenscalex = (float)_graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 1366f;
            screenscaley = (float)_graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 768f;
            ScalingFactor = new Vector3(screenscalex, screenscaley, 1);
            Global.SpriteScale = Matrix.CreateScale(ScalingFactor);
}
```

Draw() for sprite class(my towers use this code):

```
   public virtual void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.End();

        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, null, null, null, Global.SpriteScale);
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, center, null, Color.White, rotation,
        origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
}
```

Draw() for enemies:

```
    spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, null, null, null, Global.SpriteScale);
    if (alive)
    {
        base.Draw(spriteBatch);
    }
    spriteBatch.End();
```

Comment: What happens if you use ScalingFactor = new Vector3(1, 1, 1)?

Comment: It's the same thing and BTW i messed up explaining. The background goes off the screen normally (and when i did what you said)

Comment: If the scale is 1, 1, 1 then there's no scaling.  So what makes you think it's a scaling issue and not something else?

Comment: the problem was that i was dividing my screen by its resolution instead of the resolution of the background.

Comment: The thing though now is that my enemies still spawn offscreen

Comment: As a side note, it looks like you might be starting a new sprite batch for every sprite. That's generally a bad idea.

Comment: You don't have the code for spawning the enemies up, so we can't really help you on that.